# 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[MenuScene distance]: when replacing a scene

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, singleton, layer, sigabrt

In my code I have made a GameManager singleton which has a method responsible for changing scenes. The first scene I call is the MenuScene after that I replace it with the GameScene. When I do this the Console output shows:

```
2013-10-07 19:40:55.895 MyGame[56164:a0b] -[MenuScene distance]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xb460690
2013-10-07 19:40:56.011 MyGame[56164:a0b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[MenuScene distance]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xb460690'
```

From the log, I don't understand why I get `-[MenuScene distance] ...` because distance is a property of GameScene not MenuScene.

Below is GameManager method for changing scenes:

```
-(void)runSceneWithID:(SceneTypes)sceneID {
SceneTypes oldScene = currentScene;
currentScene = sceneID;
//NSString* str;
id sceneToRun = nil;
switch (sceneID)
{
    case kBeginScene:
        sceneToRun = [BeginScene node];
         break;
    case kGameScene:
        sceneToRun = [GameScene node];
        break;

    case kMenuScene:
        sceneToRun = [MenuScene node];
        break;

    default:
        CCLOG(@"Unknown ID, cannot switch scenes");
        return;
        break;
}

if (sceneToRun == nil) {
    // Revert back, since no new scene was found
    currentScene = oldScene;
    return;
}


if ([[CCDirector sharedDirector] runningScene] == nil) {
    [[CCDirector sharedDirector] runWithScene:sceneToRun];

} else {

    [[CCDirector sharedDirector] replaceScene:sceneToRun];
}
```

}

Also the call to replace scene is in a layer class which is part of the MenuScene. See below:

```
-(void)startGameScene {
[[GameManager sharedGameManager] runSceneWithID:kGameScene];

}
```

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

You get this message because the `distance` message was sent to the `MenuScene` instance which doesn't have this selector (`GameScene` does apparently).

So probably somewhere in your scene managing singleton something goes wrong and you still (or already) have a MenuScene instance where you expect to have a GameScene instance.

Add an [exception breakpoint](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-breakpoint_navigator/articles/adding_an_exception_breakpoint.html) in Xcode to see exactly where the message was coming from.

PS: be **very** careful when managing scenes in a global instance like a singleton. You could easily leak memory if you keep a strong reference to a scene (or any node for that matter) in a global instance/variable. Make sure that every scene has the dealloc method implemented with a log to see that it actually does deallocate.